# How to change icon for Facebook/twitter/youtube/Google+ Likes buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

i have page in which i show social media likes/follow/subscribe buttons from their API.

now i want to change the icons of these buttons. API does not Allow to do that, any alternate way?

my Code is for every Button:

```
<!--============== Facebook Like Icon==================-->
<li id="fc-icon">
    <div id="facebook_like_button_holder">
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTheDailyReminder&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=21&amp;appId=359856164138085" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        <div id="my_facebook_button"></div>
    </div>
</li>
<!--============== End Facebook Like Icon==================--> 

<!--============== Twitter Follow Icon==================-->
<li>
    <a class="twitter-follow-button" href="https://twitter.com/twitterdev" data-dnt="true" data-show-count = "true" data-size="large">
        <img src="smicons/twitter.png" />
    </a> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
            var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src= "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
    </script> 
</li>
<!--==============End Twitter Follow Icon==================--> 

<!--==============YouTube Subscribe Icon==================-->
<li> 
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script> 
    <script>
        function onYtEvent(payload) {
            if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
                // Add code to handle subscribe event.
            }
            else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
                // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
            }
            if (window.console) { // for debugging only
                window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="TheDailyReminder" data-layout="default" data-   count="default" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"><img src="smicons/youtube.png" /></div>
</li>
<!--==============End YouTube Subscribe Icon==================--> 

<!--==============Google Plus Subscribe Icon==================-->
<li>
    <!-- Place this tag where you want the widget to render. -->
    <div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-height="24" data-    href="https://plus.google.com/108031060121890312607" data-rel="publisher"><img src="smicons/gplus.png" /></div>
    <!-- Place this tag after the last widget tag. --> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
    </script> 
</li>
<!--==============End Google Plus Subscribe Icon==================-->
```

Here is the URL:
http://colombowebs.com/freelancer/socialinks2.html

Comment: Make generic icons if you want full control

Comment: hello Brain: how i can make it generic? can you please tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change like's or +1 buttons appearence. That is because they do not require user to confirm their choice, which would make it really easy to abuse. You'd be able to farm likes for any page.

But it is possible to create your own button for share/feed and call [Facebook SDK's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) method when clicked.

EDIT: Actually there is a way to implement some Like action with [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes) but you can't just change the icon. You should completely change its appearence.